Got securityError message when I try to input a captcha
I go the following code:
self.driver.get(self.baseUrl)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.button_paths = Page_buttons(self.driver)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.button_paths.click_accept_all_cookies()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.button_paths.click_login_link()
        time.sleep(1)

        self.button_paths.input_email(self.username_good)
        self.button_paths.click_continue_button()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.button_paths.input_good_password(self.password_good)

        API_KEY = 'a841b022c02f4e13da79e37686821cb7'
        site_url = 'https://accounts.evernote.com/login-with-password'
        site_key = '9236f198-f154-4aa9-8f4d-2e7ce9aedb5b'
        captcha_url = f"http://2captcha.com/in.php?key={API_KEY}&method=hcaptcha&sitekey={site_key}&pageurl={site_url}"
        response = requests.get(captcha_url)
        captcha_id = response.text.split('|')[1]
        while True:
            result_url = f"http://2captcha.com/res.php?key={API_KEY}&action=get&id={captcha_id}"
            result_response = requests.get(result_url)
            if result_response.text == 'CAPCHA_NOT_READY':
                time.sleep(5)  
                continue
            captcha_result = result_response.text.split('|')[1]
            break

        
        try:
            
            iframe = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='hcaptcha']"))
            )
            self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

            
            hcaptcha_response = self.driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('h-captcha-response')")
            self.driver.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value="{captcha_result}";', hcaptcha_response)

            
            self.driver.switch_to.default_content()



        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")

I get the captcha ID but when I try to insert I get the following error message:
"SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "pageXOffset" on the cross-origin object."
I know that is the purpose of a captcha.
I tried to add a preference for Firefox:
firefox_options.set_preference("privacy.trackingprotection.enabled", False)

but the same issue, I tried to manipulate the iframe better but the same issue, I tried using a VPN for the first time but again, I had the same problem, also I searched here but no other solutions or questions worked for me.
